# can't get admin url - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, url, magento2.1.11

I use the below code to get admin url of given **frontName/controllerName/Action**

```
protected $storeManagerInterface;

public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface) 
{         
    $this->storeManagerInterface = $storeManagerInterface;
}
public function getAdminUrl() 
{   
    $store = $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore();
    return $store->getUrl('emailquotepro/emailquote/create');       
}
```

but it return wrong value

> `http://host/emailquotepro/emailquote/create/`

I expect the url something like

> `https://host/admin/emailquotepro/emailquote/create/key/786fd58929a16a83d67cdf0aae51c55cdfb7afdb8f8a124b51deeda3cbc4c9a5/`

I check the areacode, it's already set as **adminhtml**.

If you have any prediction, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Can u please share ur admin and frontend route.xml

Comment: Type in command to get the admin URL

php bin/magento info:adminuri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can admin module us by below code

> \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backenHelper

use

> $backenHelper->getUrl('emailquotepro/emailquote/create')

Answer (score 0):

Type in command to get the admin URL

```
php bin/magento info:adminuri
```