# Magento 2.1 adminhtml Action 'Edit' give 404 while Index works

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, adminhtml, php-7, acl

Update:

Here is what the Developer Toolbar gives me on the 404 page:

> Mode: Developer Controler
>   Module: Magento_Backend
>   Controler Class: Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Noroute\Index
>   Controler Action Name: execute

**Note the "Noroute" in the Class URI.**

Original :

I'm creating my first Magento Module and My Index is working with a fully working filtering.

Index URL is :

```
http://local.com/admin/multiuseraccounts/permission/
```

I created the Edit action but the url trigger a 404 error :

Edit URL is :

```
http://local.com/admin/multiuseraccounts/permission/edit/permission_id/2
```

Here is my route.xml:

```
<router id="admin">
    <route id="multiuseraccounts" frontName="multiuseraccounts">
        <module name="Ramlam_MultiUserAccounts" before="Magento_Customer"/>
    </route>
</router>
```

Here is my module.xml

```
<module name="Ramlam_MultiUserAccounts" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

Index and Edit are in

```
Ramlam/MultiUserAccounts/Controller/Adminhtml/Permission/Index.php
Ramlam/MultiUserAccounts/Controller/Adminhtml/Permission/Edit.php
```

I deactivated the secure key but it didn't solve anything.

Index action is OK, Edit action triggers an error.

I tried every url combinaison possible

Magento never trigger the Edit class either xdebug nor die() is ever triggered in Edit class.

here is how the Edit url is built :

```
$this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
    'multiuseraccounts/permission/edit', 
    'permission_id' => $item['permission_id']]
);
```

Here is the acl:

```
 <acl>
     <resources>
        <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
            <resource id="Magento_Customer::customer">
                <resource id="Ramlam_MultiUserAccounts::multiuseraccounts" title="MultiUserAccounts" sortOrder="10" >
                    <resource id="Ramlam_MultiUserAccounts::multiuseraccounts_permission" title="Permission" sortOrder="40">
                        <resource id="Ramlam_MultiUserAccounts::multiuseraccounts_permission_save" title="Save" sortOrder="10" />
                        <resource id="Ramlam_MultiUserAccounts::multiuseraccounts_permission_delete" title="Delete" sortOrder="20" />
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*UPDATED*

I'd structure it like this

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjADY.jpg)

Then your admin links should be like this

etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Xigen::top_level" module="Xigen_Customer" resource="Magento_Backend::content" sortOrder="9999" title="Xigen"/>
        <add action="customer/permission/edit" id="Xigen_Customer::permission_edit" module="Xigen_Customer" parent="Xigen::top_level" resource="Xigen_Customer::permission_edit" sortOrder="9999" title="permission edit"/>
        <add action="customer/permission/index" id="Xigen_Customer::permission_index" module="Xigen_Customer" parent="Xigen::top_level" resource="Xigen_Customer::permission_index" sortOrder="9999" title="permission index"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Other than that there is a backend helper for URLs

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/210854/70343

*Second Update*

Edit controller looks like this

Controller/Adminhtml/Permission/Edit.php

```
<?php


namespace Xigen\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Permission;

class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo 'edit';
        die();
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

Other than that mot sure what to suggest. Pretty much built a working example here.

Comment: Why Index and not my Permission menu ? i will have to add more section like Permission, I can't put all in an Index folder. Thanks for the helper ! I will use that :)

Comment: Fair point. Updated.

Comment: My folder structure is like yours, so it should works, I don't understand

Comment: One more edit. Best of luck.

Comment: Edit Class is not even triggered in my case. At some point, I saw a: route='noroute' in xdebug

Comment: My error was a wrong Namespace in the Edit class. Thank for you help.